# Sharing variable between functions - rand() srand

Tags: c++, variables, encryption, random, srand

I have got to create a program that will gather input from the user and then encrypt & decrypt those characters.

I'm not very confident at coding so I'm sure many parts of my code are written poorly and not following the best practice so I have written a simple version of an algorithm where the program simply adds/subtracts a value of 2 to/from the ASCII values but I have discovered the use of the rand() and srand functions but I'm unsure how to go about using them within both my encrypt and decrypt function as a single value (static variable?).

Here is my code in its entirety at the moment.

```
#include <iostream >
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char getMenuSelection (char m);
void encrypt (char key[]);
void decrypt (char code[]);

int main ()
{
    ifstream input;
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    char menu;
    char message[80];
    //char codekey;
    //char myname[128];
     menu = 0;

    menu=getMenuSelection(menu);
    if (menu == 'e' || menu == 'E') //Option to Encrypt
    {
        cout << "Enter Message to be encrypted \n";
        cin >> message;
        input.open (message);
        encrypt (message);
        input.close();
         cout << "The Ciphertext is: " << message << endl;
        return main();
    }
     if (menu == 'd' || menu == 'D')
    {
         cout << "Enter Ciphertext to decrypt \n";
         cin >> message;
         input.open (message);
         decrypt (message);
         input.close();
         cout << "The Decrypted message is: " << message << endl;
        return main();
     }
    if (menu == 'q' || menu == 'Q')
     {
         cout << "Program exiting.";
         cin.ignore();
         return 0;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
     }

 char getMenuSelection (char m) // Get the menu function
 {
     cout << "|||_______Welcome To Elliotts Encryption_______|||\n";
     cout << "|||__________and Deciphering Program___________|||\n";
     cout << "|||____________________________________________|||\n";
     cout << "|||______Please select 'E' to encrypt a________|||\n";
     cout << "|||____message, 'D' to decipher a message______|||\n";
     cout << "|||______________Or 'Q' to Quit________________|||\n";
     cin >> m;

 switch (m)
     {
        case 'e':
        case 'E':   cout << "Encryption." << endl;
                  break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':   cout <<  "Decryption." << endl;
                    break;
            case 'q':
        case 'Q':   cout <<  "Quitting" << endl;
                break;
        default: cout << "Error, Please try another message. ";
                 return getMenuSelection(m);
    }
    return (m);
 }
int random (int r)
 {
    srand(time(0));
    r=rand();
    return r;
  }
void encrypt (char key[], int r) //encryption function.
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) key[i] += r;
}
 void decrypt (char code[], int r) //decryption function.
 {
     for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) code[i] -= r;
 }
```

This code currently doesn't execute due to ' undefined reference to 'encrypt(char*) '

**Question**

I am asking how to generate the random number and incorporate this into my encrypt and decrypt functions.

1. Would the use of a static or global variable make this work as is?
2. Would I need to create separate class files for both functions?
3. Any other possibilities?

I understand that I will not be given the correct code in full but it would help me greatly if anyone could just point me in the right way or tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: To use random numbers for encryption, you need to make sure that (1) Both you and your recipient have *exactly* the same algorithm (not just "whatever local compiler's rand() does"), and (2) Both of you seed the RNG with the same key value, not something random, like a clock. If you do both of those things, then you can do something simple like add or xor each character of the message with numbers from the RNG, essentially duplicating a one-time-pad. Then you need to worry about key exchange...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Would the use of a static or global variable make this work as is?

Not precisely. The problem here is simply that the function signatures you are declaring and calling:

```
void encrypt (char key[]);
```

does not match the signature of the function you are defining:

```
void encrypt (char key[], int r);
```

This makes it a separate function (due to function overloading).

Making `r` a global variable might be *part* of a solution, but you will still need to make the signatures for this function consistent.

As far as how you generate that value, that's up to you. Presumably it'll need to be either set by the user or made part of the message, though; using a random number will make it impossible to decrypt a message unless you randomly generate the same number.

> 2. Would I need to create separate class files for both functions?

No. You don't need any classes (or multiple files) here.